# Hard Multivariable Calculus Question

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

The graph of a function z=f(x,y) can always be parametrized as (x,y,f(x,y)). Show that in this case the "old way" (using the derivative and gradient) and the "new way" (Parametrizing the surface and using T vectors) for finding the tangent plane at a point always agree.

I have no idea how to do this problem. I think he wants us to show that two different ways lead to the same tangent plane at a point. one is using the partial derivatives, the second is doing it via T vectors. Can someone run me through the steps? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When tackling a problem such as this, try a couple of specific function $z=f(x,y)$ and try it both ways. See if this gives you an idea of how to tackle the general problem.

Comment: This question is word-for-word identical to [the one you posted less than half a day ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2771648/265466). If you didn’t get a satisfactory (or any) answer the first time, you should edit your original question to add more context instead just asking the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

The "old way", was to define a surface.

$S: F(x,y,z) = k$
and then find $dS = \nabla F = (\frac {\partial F}{\partial x},\frac {\partial F}{\partial y},\frac {\partial F}{\partial z})$

And the "new way" defines the surface parmetrically.

$x = f(s,t)\\
y = g(s,t)\\
z = h(s,t)$

$dS = (\frac {\partial f}{\partial s},\frac {\partial g}{\partial s},\frac {\partial h}{\partial s})\times(\frac {\partial f}{\partial t},\frac {\partial g}{\partial t},\frac {\partial h}{\partial t})$

But there is no reason $x,y$ can't be your parameters.

Show that:

$\nabla (z- f(x,y)) = (1,0,\frac {\partial z}{\partial x})\times(0,1,\frac {\partial z}{\partial y})$

Comment: Can you please write out the steps for me?

Comment: $(-\frac {\partial f}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial f}{\partial y},1)= (-\frac {\partial f}{\partial x},-\frac {\partial f}{\partial y},1)$